# how to get the mean, min, etc of a bunch of values inside of a for loop python

Tags: python

```
import statistics
from random import seed, choice
import random
import turtle
seed(20190101)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(-25,-25,15,15)
turtle.delay(0)




def pa():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = 100

    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(["N","S","E","W"])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == "S":
            y = y - 1
        elif step == "E":
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1

        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.shape("circle")
        turtle.turtlesize(2)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.stamp()
        if x == 50:
            break
        elif y == 50:
            break
        for x, y in range (x):
            print("The minimum is" min(x)
            print("The mean is" mean)
            print("The variance is" pstdev)

pa()
```

Hello, I just have a question. So I have a random walk simulator that calcuates x and y coordinates inside of a for loop. My question is how am I supposed to get all of the values from the results of the for loop and calculate the mean, min, etc.

Do I make it into the list? I tried using the statistics module inside of python.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Put it in a list, anf calculate min/max/mean/variance at the end. It's the simple and straightforward solution.

If you then realize it uses too much memory (unlikely) you can optimize it further, e.g. the max value is easy to calculate as you go.

Comment: how would i put it in a list? Would I do at the end of the loop ``` list = x , y ```

Comment: `mylist += [(x,y)]` to append a tuple to a list. You'll have to do that pnce per loop iteration, so you have a copy of all the positions over time.

Comment: so put the mylist += [(x,y)] inside of the for loop?

Comment: its also saying mylist is undefined.. do I make it into a variable?

Comment: Yes and yes. Commenttoshort.