# Having an issue converting this into a list and getting the mean from a for loop python

Tags: python

```
import statistics
import random
import turtle
from random import seed, choice
seed(20190101)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(-25,-25,25,25)



def pa():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = 10

    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(["N","S","E","W"])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == "S":
            y = y - 1
        elif step == "E":
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1

        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.shape("circle")
        turtle.turtlesize(2)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.stamp()
        if x == 50:
                break
        elif y == 50:
                break
        mylist = [(x,y)]

        y = ''.join(mylist)

        z = int(y)

    print(statistics.mean(z))  
    return (x,y)

pa()
```

I'm having issues trying to get mean of the list I created inside of this for loop. For some reason, it isnt converting into the list correctly, or it just is not getting the values into integers correctly. I have no idea why my values from my list are not working

Comment: What do you want to happen when `y = -1` and you join it as a string with `x`? Because you can't convert `'-1-2'` into an integer.

Comment: well i'm just trying to get an average of all of the values inside of the list so I was trying a bunch of different things.

Comment: This `y = ''.join(mylist)` is supposed to average the values of the list?

Comment: no, i'm just trying to get all of the values of the list correctly. Then I was going to try statistics.mean(mylist) after

Comment: Which values do you want the mean of? Also, I don't see the point in creating a function which takes no parameters and is called only once. Can you explain your code a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a list for each value you want to get the mean for. Then append values to the list, and use the `mean()` at the end:

```
import statistics
import random
import turtle
from random import seed, choice
seed(20190101)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(-25,-25,25,25)



def pa():
    # create empty lists
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    xy_list = []

    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = 10

    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(["N","S","E","W"])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == "S":
            y = y - 1
        elif step == "E":
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1

        turtle.color("black")
        turtle.shape("circle")
        turtle.turtlesize(2)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.stamp()

        # append values to the lists
        x_list.append(x)
        y_list.append(y)
        xy_list.extend((x,y))

        if x == 50:
                break
        elif y == 50:
                break


    # apply mean to each list
    print(statistics.mean(x_list), statistics.mean(y_list))
    print(statistics.mean(xy_list))
    return (x,y)

pa()
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I combine the means? I need them to be one value. Like combine the means of the x and the y

Comment: You can just have a list that contains both x and y values as in my edited code above. Or, since we know there are the same number of x values as y values, you can just average the two means `combined_mean = (statistics.mean(x_list) + statistics.mean(y_list)) / 2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to append the values to `mylist` as the loop progresses, not overwrite it -

```
mylist = [(x, y)]
```

will overwrite `mylist` every iteration with the current `x` and `y`. As [Filip Haglund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013251/how-to-get-the-mean-min-etc-of-a-bunch-of-values-inside-of-a-for-loop-python/59013353#59013353) to your previous question said, you need to [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the values to the list each time, i.e.

```
mylist += [(x, y)]
```

or

```
mylist.append((x, y))
```

In order to do that you need `mylist` to be declared as a `list`, in this case that should be before the loop -

```py
def pa()
    mylist = list()
    #...
    for i in range(n):
        #...
        mylist += [(x, y)]
```

This will give you a `list` of `tuples` containing all the `x` and `y` pairs which can then be averaged as needed.

Note that this will be easier if you use two `list`s instead of a `list` of `tuple`s, i.e.

```py
def pa()
    x_list = list()
    #...
    for i in range(n):
        #...
        x_list += [x]
        y_list += [y]
    print(statistics.mean(x_list), statistics.mean(y_list))
```

Comment: how do I combine the means of the x and y,

Comment: @Oklol2958 in what way do you need them combined? Do you need the sum of their averages? The average distance from `(0,0)`? Some sort of piecewise combination?